# Adding Thumbnail Image to Bootstrap Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I am trying to add a user's profile picture to a dropdown menu using Bootstrap 3.

Here is a code snippet of the dropdown menu currently in my code:

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="usernameHeaderField"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Administrator <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <img class="thumbnail" style="height:100px; float-left; margin:10px" src="default.jpg">

      <li>
        <a href="profile.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="sendEmail.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope-o"></i>Send email report</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="settings.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is what it currently looks like:

[image: Broken dropdown menu with picutrue]

I have tried putting the unordered list inside of a div and gave the div the dropdown class, but this broke the nice style of the links in this menu. Also it would require a lot more formatting to move the list next to the picture.

Is there any way to create a dropdown menu with a picture floated to the left of the list items??

Thank you in advance for any help with this problem.

Comment: take div with **class="row"** and make 2 divs with class,  **col-md- 4 ( for image )**  and **col-md-8 ( for list items )**

Comment: Thanks for this idea! It mostly worked. From what I understand the dropdown menu has to have a certain order of inheritance of classes. Adding a row with divs breaks that chain so the formatting does not get applied appropriately. I was able to find a workaround though. Thanks for your help!